# How to transfer data from one system to another system's HDFS (connected through LAN) using Flume?

Tags: hdfs, lan, transfer, hadoop-streaming, flume

I have a computer in LAN Connection . I need to transfer data from the system to another system's HDFS location using flume.

I have tried using ip address of the sink system, but it didn't work. Please help..

Regards,

Athiram

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import logs from a website to hdfs using flume?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295697/how-to-import-logs-from-a-website-to-hdfs-using-flume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using avro mechanism.

**The flume has to be installed in both the machines. A config file with the following codes has to be made to be run in the source system , where the logs are generated.**

```
a1.sources = tail-file
a1.channels = c1
a1.sinks=avro-sink

a1.sources.tail-file.channels = c1
a1.sinks.avro-sink.channel = c1
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000

a1.sources.tail-file.type = spooldir
a1.sources.tail-file.spoolDir =<location of spool directory>
a1.sources.tail-file.channels = c1
a1.sinks.avro-sink.type = avro
a1.sinks.avro-sink.hostname = <IP Address of destination system where the data has to    be written>   
a1.sinks.avro-sink.port = 11111
```

**A config file with the following codes has to be made to be run in the destination system , where the logs are generated.**

```
a2.sources = avro-collection-source
a2.sinks = hdfs-sink
a2.channels = mem-channel

a2.sources.avro-collection-source.channels = mem-channel
a2.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = mem-channel
a2.channels.mem-channel.type = memory
a2.channels.mem-channel.capacity = 1000

a2.sources.avro-collection-source.type = avro
a2.sources.avro-collection-source.bind = localhost
a2.sources.avro-collection-source.port = 44444

a2.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
a2.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a2.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.filePrefix =  testing
a2.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/
```

Now, the data from the log file in the source system will be written to hdfs system in the destination system.

Regards,

Athiram